# Trying to write output of xml file into a txt file

Tags: python, xml

Below is my code, When executed, the text file is not created, nothing is being read from the XML file, furthermore, no errors are coming up, basically nothing is happening. any suggestions ??

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

def main():
    b = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('books.xml')
    persons = b.findall("book")
    for element in persons:
        author, title, genre, price, publish, description = book_data_from_element(element)
        f = open('offload.txt', 'w')
        f.write(author, title, genre, price, publish, description)
        f.close()

def book_data_from_element(element):
    author = element.find("author").text
    title = element.find("title").text
    genre = element.find("genre").text
    price = element.find("price").text
    publish = element.find("publish_date").text
    description = element.find("description").text
    return author, title, genre, price, publish, description
```

Comment: Maybe you should call the main method

Comment: Also, your loop re-creates the .txt each time and does not append values. So only last element of XML will show. Looking into [with()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html): `with open("offload.txt", "a") as myfile: myfile.write(author, title, genre, price, publish, description)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is running fine. This particular module defines two functions: `main` and `book_data_from_element`. It does not call either. Python is not like C or Java, where the name `main` is special because it is the entry point to your program. To execute `main` or any other function, you have to run it in the module. Add the following lines to the bottom of your module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The line `if __name__ == '__main__':` is called an import guard. It prevents `main` from running if you are actually importing the module into another module. It works because `__name__` will be the actual name used for importing and not `'__main__'` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling main method, the simplest way is to write

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Save file and call it from console, like `python your_file.py`

Also you could use `with` context manager instead of

```
    f = open('offload.txt', 'w')
    f.write(author, title, genre, price, publish, description)
    f.close()
```